# SQL Confused over ON UPDATE and ON DELETE

Tags: sql, cascade, cascading-deletes, restrict

I need to create a database using sql for my reviews site.  I tried to use the on delete and on update constraints but I'm not sure if they are right.
I created three tables a 'cars'(my review items) 'reviews'(holds the reviews) and a 'users' one. I linked cars_id and users_id with reviews table. I used on update cascade and on delete cascade for both. I'm not sure if that's right. Can someone help me understand them more?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: Its not SQL that is confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is a matter of data modelling.**

Ask yourself the question:

*"If I delete a car, do I want to delete the relational records of other tables too?"*

If YES put it to CASCADE etc.

Or:

*"If I delete a user, do I want to delete his cars too?"*

*"If I delete a car, do I want do delete the corresponding user too?"*

Maybe a good idea to read first here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database

and then here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1-olh/de/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html